# Puppet: Add mount point as a windows shared drive

Tags: puppet

How to add a windows share drive on the fileserver.conf? and use this as a mounting point for files.

Guessing if this can't be done. Do I need to install samba services and then mount the windows share drive using the mount command?

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need samba but puppet can ensure samba and all dependencies are installed. so all you need
is proper puppet manifests.
you can look at an example puppet samba module here.
https://github.com/AllPlayers/puppet-samba

Look at smb.conf.erb, thats where you would define all the samba mount points.

Comment: Umm. For the puppet master as well?

Comment: No, Module definitions are generic. Defining a module doesnt install it on a machine. You would have a 'node' definition for that.

Comment: node 'a-sample-machine.yourdomain.com' inherits basemachine {
    include samba::server

Comment: My question was. A puppet module included on the master puppet node can be utilized to configure the server as well?. Guessing it cant since the master puppet is also a client.